# rsync fails on MacOS for IPV6 addresses with "ssh: Could not resolve hostname"

Tags: macos, ipv6, rsync

Copying files with rsync to a remote computer using the remotes IPv6 address fails on MacOS 10.14.6. It seems that the IPv6 address is not correctly forwarded to ssh, but all my attempts using brackets and escaping the IP failed.

```
$ rsync -6 /local/path/to/file.tar.gz remoteusername@[2001:x:x:x:x:x:x:x]:/path/to/remote/dir/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname [2001: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Indicating the usage of IPv6 with `rsync -6 -e "ssh -6" [source] [target]` also failed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the rsync version shipped with MacOS apparently doesn't handle IPv6 addresses correctly.

```
$ /usr/bin/rsync --version
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
```

Using MacProts rsync solved the problem and the command as stated in the question works as expected

```
$ /opt/local/bin/rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround worked for me at the rsync 2.6.9 version.

core@4TssX2-A:~ $ rsync -av -e 'ssh -l root' ./bbb.txt '[IPV6]:/tmp'
building file list ... done

sent 76 bytes  received 20 bytes  192.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00